# child products of configurable products seen as simple products

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have created few configyrable product on my magento bike store, but on the frontend i see their associated products as simple products and with no picture. I need to have ONLY the main products (configurable products) and no child products seen as simple products. Where i did wrong?

Screenshot:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Like descriptions/screenshots etc so that it is more obvious what the problem is.

Comment: details  http://prntscr.com/4z6mh0

Comment: Try set simple product "visibility" attribute to "Not Visible Individually".

Comment: ha? how can I do it?

Comment: Anyone? please.. I cannot set simple products ot visible because i have other simple products that i must show on frontend...